# My dual boot laptop can't find Wireless connections. (Kali Linux)

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

Here is ifconfig:
eth0: flags=4163  mtu 1500
        inet IP  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast IP
        inet6 fe80::7a45:c4ff:feb0:5a51  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
        ether 78:45:c4:b0:5a:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 68704  bytes 86032233 (82.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 45126  bytes 4304694 (4.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 24  bytes 1400 (1.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24  bytes 1400 (1.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Here is iwconfig:

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

I installed 2010-06-25 wirless drivers, but after reboot wlan1 and wlan0 disappeared. Anyway, with wireless dirvers I can't find my wirless network in settings. How I can fix that?

I tried everything,but nothing. :(

**SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH. :| **